# How to concatenate 2 audio files, one in left channel one in right channel

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, audio, core-audio

I have a stereo recording of a word and I have a 2nd recording of the same word being recorded on a mobile device by an end user, also in stereo.

I need to

1. Convert these both audio files into mono.
2. Combine these 2 new mono audio files so when the resulting audio file is 
   played back the end user hears my recording in their left ear (channel) and 
   their recording in their right ear (channel).

This needs to be done natively for both operating systems (iOS and Android).

Much appreciated if anyone has some example code or thoughts they would like to share with me.

Comment: This should be achievable via ffmpeg but I don't know how.

Comment: as an educational challenge fine looks like a nice problem to solve however from a productivity perspective there are command line tools like ffmpeg to achieve each of those steps quicker and more simply ... I suggest you solve those steps first using ffmepg on the command line then craft a mobile equivalent ... at least this way you have something working to bounce your mobile solution against ... on your laptop I suggest you install a free audio tool called Audacity ... this can render audio files graphically